# Is this Differential equation a linear DE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\Large{y\frac{dy}{dx}-xy=0}$

Could you please explain to me why it is or isn't?

Much obliged, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO, it's not a linear DE, because you have a multiplication of the unknown function $y$ by its derivative $dy/dx$.

If you factor by $y$,

$$y\biggl(\frac{dy}{dx}-x\biggr)=0$$

You can solve ir rather easily, imposing conditions:
$$y=0\quad\mathrm{OR}\quad\frac{dy}{dx}-x=0$$

The second condition is a linear DE. But the original DE is not.

Comment: Note that the solution to the differential equation for $x, y \in \mathbb R$ is not either the function $y=0$ throughout or $y=\frac {x^2}2+C$ throughout. The non-constant solution can be applied to any open set, with the function set equal to zero on the (closed) complement. Different (open) components of the open set can have different values for $C$. The solution may be further constrained if it is required to be continuous, for example, or everywhere differentiable.